# How to remove space from excel reading from Java

Tags: java, excel

Im importing Excel data to Java program. Having a column that should eliminate whitespace in case user mistype on the column.

Example value : "12341 "

i've used

```
 replaceAll("\\s+", "");
 replaceAll(" ", "");
 StringUtils.trim(stringValue);
```

However, it still return "12341 " with length :6. It didn't remove the unnecessary white-spaces

### EDIT

Complete code for replace return.

```
stringArray[x] = stringArray[x].replaceAll("\\s+", "");
stringArray[x] = stringArray[x].replaceAll(" ", "");
stringArray[x] = StringUtils.trim(stringArray[x]);
```

Comment: Maybe the space is a non breaking space? So try `.replace("\u00A0", "")`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
stringValue = stringValue.replaceAll(" ", "");
```

You need to use the returned value.

Comment: yes i have used to referenced back as below . 
stringArray[x] = stringArray[x].replaceAll(" ", ""); however, the result remain the same makes me out of clues

Comment: I don't see you code. Probably you're changing back the string values.

Comment: I've post on the EDIT

Comment: I've tested them all. They all work fine. Maybe you're reassigning `stringValue[x]` somewhere else? Check it again.

Comment: i found out that is unbreaking white-spaces suggested by @axel Richter. 
.replace("\u00A0", "") this works fine to me. thx

Answer (score 0):

I too face the same problem and i resolved it by using

text = text.replaceAll("[^\x00-\x7F]", "");

And make sure this will remove your special character too

Ref link :
https://howtodoinjava.com/regex/java-clean-ascii-text-non-printable-chars/